# PCA can't get color on scatterplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, pca

I'm doing a mini project on my own. I'm trying this thing with PCA. After i have plotted my graph, I can't seem to get the color out. These are the steps below for my code. Before this i have scaled and transformed the data. After scaling i did a PCA. These are the steps. First:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca= PCA(n_components= 2)
pca.fit(scaled_data)

x_pca= pca.transform(scaled_data)

principaldf= pd.DataFrame(data=x_pca, 
                      columns=['principal component 1', 
                              'principal component 2'])
```

**After this i combined both dataframes and got this.**

```
new_df= principaldf.join(df_features)
new_df.head()
```

[image]

**Next i attempted to plot the graph with the code below:**

```
color= ['r','g']
plt.scatter(x_pca[:, 0], x_pca[:, 1],
     edgecolor='none', alpha=0.5, c= color)
plt.xlabel('component 1')
plt.ylabel('component 2')
```

I got this error

> V**alueError: 'c' argument has 2 elements, which is not acceptable for
>   use with 'x' with size 261, 'y' with size 261.**

[image]

Can anyone please advise or help? Hope my question was clear enough. thanks!

Comment: what variable do you want to actually color your points by? ie which points are red and which are green?

Comment: hello @Simon, for Gender will like to get red and green. Thanks

Comment: @desertnaut whats a full trace? and isnt it in text format? lol. read the link u sent and got no clue what it even means

Comment: It means that your *error message* should be posted as *text*, and not as a screenshot image as you have done here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like:

Assign numerical values to `Gender`:

```
new_df['Gender'] = new_df['Gender'].replace({'Male':0, 'Female':1})
```

Then plot using color and cmap:

```
plt.scatter(x_pca[:, 0], x_pca[:, 1], edgecolor='none', alpha=0.5,
            c=new_df['Gender'], cmap='RdYlGn')
```

When you pass in a 2 item list like `['r', 'g']` it doesnt know which points should be which colour

Comment: Hello @Simon! I have tried running the code but it returned this error. **ValueError: 'c' argument must either be valid as mpl color(s) or as numbers to be mapped to colors. Here c = 0        Male**

Comment: Or is it possible that I might have gotten the whole algo wrong in the first place?